# "Ate cheeseburger" or "ate a cheeseburger"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles

Which of the following is correct?

> - Ate **a** cheese burger last night.
> - Ate cheese burger last night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there were an enormous cheeseburger and you cut it up and served pieces of it to separate people, then you could say you “ate cheeseburger” last night. Otherwise, *cheeseburger* is a count noun and you have to use a count determiner like *a* with it.

As a side note, we do write *cheeseburger* as a single word, not separately as *cheese burger*.

Answer (score 6):

[I|you|we] ate **a** cheeseburger last night.

Comment: Though in the case of "we" and plural "you", it would probably be "ate cheeseburgers".